# Django Template not rendering

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-templates

I am trying to load a list of objects from a MySQL database using Django templates. I can load the objects from the database using `Product.objects.values()` and convert it into a dict, then pass that dict as a context to the render function. But when I load my page, it does not iterate the dictionary. Has anyone any ideas?

```
 def product(request):
    print(Product.objects.values())

    d = Product.objects.values()

    newdict = {}

    for entry in d:
        name = entry.pop('name')  # remove and return the name field to use as a key
        newdict[name] = entry

    print(newdict)
    return render(request, 'product.html', newdict)




 <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 add_to_cart_block">

            {% for item in newdict.items %}
            {{newdict|length}}
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="price">{{item}}</p>
                    <p class="price_discounted">149.90 $</p>
                    <form method="get" action="cart.html">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="colors">Color</label>
                            <select class="custom-select" id="colors">
                                <option selected>Select</option>
                                <option value="1">Blue</option>
                                <option value="2">Red</option>
                                <option value="3">Green</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Quantity :</label>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" value="1">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="cart.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Cart
                        </a>
                    </form>
                    <div class="product_rassurance">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-2x"></i><br/>Fast delivery</li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x"></i><br/>Secure payment</li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i><br/>+33 1 22 54 65 60</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews_product p-3 mb-2 ">
                        3 reviews
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        (4/5)
                        <a class="pull-right" href="#reviews">View all reviews</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="datasheet p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white">
                        <a href="" class="text-white"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Download DataSheet</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any good reason for using `.values()` and a dictionary mangling instead of just `.all()`.

Comment: When I use .all() it passed a queryset. I need to convert that to a dictionary so I can iterate it with the template.

Comment: Do you know how to convert .all() to a dict?

Comment: You do **not** need to convert a queryset to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your views, it looks like the problem lies with the context object. The context is a dictionary, and you are passing `newdict` as the context. That means that `newdict`'s items will be the keys in the context. To fix this problem, you would need to write the line as follows:

```
return render(request, 'product.html', {'newdict': newdict})
```

However, there is a better way to display in a template. Here is an example:

views.py

```
@login_required
def account_index():
    accounts = Account.objects.all()
    context = {'accounts': accounts}
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)
```

accounts/index.html

```
<tbody>
      {% for account in accounts %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ account.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ account.number }}</td>
              <td>{{ account.route }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Now I can't access the dictionary values as the value is a dictionary. When I go item.name or item.desc it doesn't work. It just prints the dictionary literally. Have you any thoughts?

Comment: @AdamHoward Check out the edit to my answer and see if that's a better solution for you.

Comment: Yes, it made things a bit more clear, thank you again. Unfortunately, I still can't access my product objects attributes with item.name and item.desc. I printed out the context and this is what I get: {'products': <QuerySet [<Product: Product object (1)>]>}. 

I try looping through the objects in the template with {% for item in products.items %} and accessing each with item.name and item.desc but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you still sending the products over as a custom dictionary? If you send it over using `all()`, then you don't have to call `items`. You can just do `{% for prod in products %}`. Do you think that would work?